# uploading file using ajax - echo from PHP tells that file is uploaded, but file is not there

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

Hello I am trying to get to work this piece of code:

I am trying to build intelligent images uploader, that will care about the html 5 multiple selection bug (or feature as someone can say) which will delete "previous files" when I decide to select few extra. Also it has some primitive approach to permit user selecting file that was selected previously.

This part works fine, I am seeing images previews and also echoing "file" into console corresponds to number of files.

What is strange is return (echo) from PHP script which says that file is in /tmp directory and also size is correct, but file don't get moved.

I checked permissions and set uploaded folder to "lucky" 777.
I checked /tmp folder and file is no there but PHP script is saying taht is here.
I know about that you can't set , it is logical why you can't, but should echo from PHP script shows size and tmp location of this file then if this is a issue ?

code here:

```
var noveSub = [];
var noveSubMeno = [];
var noveSubVelkost = [];

function samotnyUpload() {
    var fd = new FormData();    
    fd.append('upload', noveSub[0]);
// trying just first file for testing

    $.ajax({
        url: '/upload/upload.php',
        data: fd,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

function pridatSubory() {
$("li.pridaj").click(function() {
    $("input").trigger("click");
});

function pushniNovy(subor) {
    noveSub.push(subor);
    noveSubMeno.push(subor.name);
    noveSubVelkost.push(subor.size);
    previewNovy(subor);
}

function previewNovy(subor) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.file = subor; 
    li.appendChild(img);
    $(li).insertBefore("li.pridaj");    
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(subor);
}

var inputElement = document.getElementById("vyberSubor");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
function handleFiles() {
    var sub = this.files; 
    for (i=0; i<sub.length; i++) {
        pos = noveSubMeno.indexOf(sub[i].name);
        if (pos !== -1) {
            if (noveSubVelkost[pos] !== sub[i].size) {
                pushniNovy(sub[i]);
            }
        } else {
            pushniNovy(sub[i]);
        } 
    }
}
```

PHP FILE :

```
   <?php
if ($_FILES["upload"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["upload"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["upload"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["upload"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];
  echo "<br><br>";
  echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  }
?>
```

OUTPUT FROM PHP FILE in console:

```
Upload: erb128.png<br>Type: image/png<br>Size: 4.734375 kB<br>Stored in: /tmp/phpdTy053<br><br>
```

Comment: I would suggest using an absolute path in the second argument of your move_uploaded_file. For example, try `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);`

Comment: Unlucky, this did not help...

Comment: Make sure the user that the web server is running as has permission to write to the upload/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

It may actually be a syntax problem. You're mixing strings and variables in your move_uploaded_file call. Try this instead:

```
$destination = "upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $destination);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Localhost or an internet server? You'll probably need to check to see if there's a setting in php.ini that would deny access to PHP to move a file. I think I was wrong anyway - now I'm thinking it would still execute the move_uploaded_file command just echo out the returned result to the page.

Comment: localhost ... but I think that upload is possible because on other websites with simple upload forms files are uloading just fine

Answer (score 0):

I rethink this approach. to use PUT for upload. I have read that some benefits are:

- small memory footprint even if You are uploading very big files
- and also saw scripts that are able to pause upload.

changes to code (only draft):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function samotnyUpload() {
        xhr.open("put", "http://pingpong.local/upload/upload.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", noveSubMeno[0]);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", noveSubVelkost[0]);
        xhr.send(noveSub[0]);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
              }
         };
    }
```

and PHP script:

```
<?php
$filename = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'];
echo $filename;
$filesize = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_SIZE'];
echo $filesize;
$in = fopen('php://input','r');
$tmp = fopen('tempfile.ext','w');
while($data = fread($in, 1024)) fwrite($tmp, $data);
fclose($in);
fclose($tmp);
?>
```